# Linux service to listen on multiple sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, port, tcpserver

We have an application (written in C++) running on Linux that listens on a port for an incoming request.

We have a requirement for the same service to listen to many ports i.e. potentially 10,000’s.

I think the only solutions is to setup 10,000 of sockets or is there a more intelligent way of doing this. Is there a feature of the newer kernel that I don’t know about?

Comment: Why would you have 10,000 *listening* sockets for the same application?  I am having trouble envisioning a situation where this is necessary or smart.

Comment: Its complex but its a load balanced environment where the Content server talks back through the Virtual servers of the Lb to access services on its self. Strange and not my design but we need to support it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at `C10K` [problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

Basically the answer depends on what type of stuff your going to do.

Comment: Hi, I know this web site well. What specifically are you referring to? Its TCP Not UDP.